# How can I test functions that are inside a component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

is there a way to test functions that are inside components.
For my example I have a component called `LoginPopUp` inside the component there is a login form:

```
        <div data-testid="popup" className="popup-content">           
            <h3 className="title">Login form </h3>
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input data-testid="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" className="form-control"
                           type="email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input data-testid="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" className="form-control"
                           type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>                  
                <button data-testid="loginBtn" onClick={handleLogin} type={"submit"}
                        className="popup-btn-login">Login
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

as you can see this is my form and the login button is type submit, the button calls `handleLogin` on click  here is the function

```
function handleLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (email === 'test@test.com' && password === '123') {
        localStorage.setItem('token', true);
        localStorage.setItem('email', email)
        closePopup(false)
    } else {
        closePopup(true);
        setError(true);
    }
}
```

I wrote tests for the component itself but I want to test the behavior of the `handleLogin` in case of success and failure of the login

Comment: Please give a [mre], including the _tests_, that allows other people to recreate the issue. Presumably `handleLogin` is defined _inside_ the component, you can't call it directly, so it's an implementation detail - you should test the behaviour it implements by interacting with the component as a user would.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get your point? If you want to test how the function works when it's successful, just enter the current email and password and if you want to test when it's failed, just enter the wrong input.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, but when I run my tests with coverage, I get prompted that my function is not covered by the tests.